# Unable To Open/Decompress xml.gzip or zip.gzip Files

Tags: xml, zip, cygwin, gzip, 7zip

I've been given 2 files and told to extract/decompress them to get the contents inside.
Example: ***long-file-name.xml.gzip*** & ***other-long-file.zip.gzip***

My workstation is Win10. I don't have access to Mac or Linux machine, I'd have to go home and wipe a machine and install it there.

These 2 files were spit out of an application on a server I don't have access to. I'm really confused why it had the .gzip format instead of .gz.

Neither 7Zip nor Cygwin "gunzip" will cooperate.
7Zip says "Cannot open the file as [gzip] archive; is not archive" for both files.
gunzip seems to want the file to be in .gz format... I was told .gzip and .gz should both be treated the same, however.

Thanks in advance for any replies, please be kind I don't work with files like this at all.

Comment: I've never seen ".gzip" used as the suffix. Only ".gz". Indeed, your tools are saying that they are not, in fact, gzip streams. You need to include the first 20 bytes or so of each file in hex in your question, and then maybe we can deduce what they are.

Answer (score 0):

check the file are what you expect:

```
 $ file map.text.gzip
map.text.gzip: gzip compressed data, was "map.text", last modified: Thu Jul 23 18:08:26 2020, from Unix, original size modulo 2^32 15872

$ gunzip map.text.gzip
gzip: map.text.gzip: unknown suffix -- ignored
```

If so, just copy with the right extension and unpack

```
$ cp map.text.gzip map.text.gz

$ gunzip -kv  map.text.gz
map.text.gz:     86.3% -- created map.text
```